# Resolv.getaddress not resolving the FQDN that has entry in /etc/host

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using Ruby version: 2.0. The function Resolv.getaddress(fqdn) is returning following error when used in rails application.

```
    Parameters: {"fqdn"=>"1kzdm.scalsoln.in"}
    Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 64ms

    Resolv::ResolvError (no address for 1kzdm.scalsoln.in):
```

I'm have entry for this host in /etc/hosts and is resolvable using ping.
How can I make the Resolv.getaddress() function to read entries in /etc/hosts file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should just work like you expect - and it does on my machine.

`Resolve::Hosts` doesn't read in /etc/hosts on every resolution, though. It reads the file on first resolution and it is then cached for the subsequent calls. Perhaps you simply need to restart your server process to force a reload of the /etc/hosts file?

To work around the caching (ie. always resolve using non-cached data) you can create a new `Resolv` instance every time you want to look something up:

```
Resolv.new.getaddress("1kzdm.scalsoln.in")
```

(note the `new` in there).

Comment: Thanks Jakob, its working after restarting the rails server. But I'm not understanding when the /etc/hosts contents will be cached. In irb also its working fine. Onlyy in rails application its not working, every time we call action its a new call right?

Comment: As far as I can tell it reads the /etc/hosts file on the first `getaddress` lookup and then caches the contents for as long as the current process lives. In a Rails application that process can live on for a long time (ie until it is killed for whatever reason).

Comment: Ok, so its not reliable to use Resolv.getaddress, is there any better alternative for host name resolution in Ruby. My requirement mainly include adding host entry to /etc/hosts if its resolvable to make it resolvable.